# Dataset for access control policies?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data

I'm working on a dynamic access control policy generation model using machine learning and I need a real dataset to evaluate the performance. Is there any access control policy dataset consisting entities (device, users), operations, roles, attributes, and permission policies?

I only could find the datasets having network traffic and access logs without any actual permission policies. If the dataset is related IoT (Internet of Things) or WSN (Wireless Sensor Networks) that would be ideal. If anyone knows a good dataset that would be a big help. Also, please mention the source paper (if any) so I can cite it.